# Doxygen and C++: link to one of two templated functions

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have doxygen-documented code such as this:

```
/// This is foo 1
template <class T>
int foo(T);

/// This is foo 2
template <class T, class U>
int foo(T, U);
```

I want to place a link in the documentation foo 2 to foo 1, but this does not work (or variations thereof)

```
/// This is foo 1
template <class T>
int foo(T);

/** This is foo 2

  See foo(T) for details.
*/
template <class T, class U>
int foo(T, U);
```

doxygen complains with errors such as

```
Reference to function 'foo' is ambiguous
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: I just tried your example with the current doxygen version (1.8.17) and a default doxygen configuration file and here I see the link and no warning. With some older versions the results for me are the same. So please also show the changes you made to your doxygen configuration file in comparison to the default file.

Comment: It is doxygen 1.8.16. But I realize now that the issue may come from doxygen postprocessing. We use the doxygen xml output and process this further.

Comment: When enabling GENERATE_XML I don't see a message either (with 1.8.17 nor with 1.8.16). Would indeed be good to clear from where the message comes (i.e. doxygen or from the post processing).